# Can you sort a list like $(1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 5, 1)$ without arbitrary swaps?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, algorithms, sorting

### Background

Imagine you have a tuple of integers, say $t=(1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 5, 1)$. Then you can order the list with your favourite sorting algorithm and obtain $t'=(5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0)$. An alternative way of finding this element is

$$
t'=\max\{ gt : g\in S_7 \}
$$
for the symmetric group $S_7$, and where we mean max with respect to lexicographical order. Of course listing all possible permutations is inefficient, which is why we invented sorting.

### Actual Question

Now take a subgroup $G\trianglelefteq S_7$, which acts on tuples of integers; for our example take the group generated by the two cycles $(12)(34)$ and $(567)$. How do we find
$$
t''=\max\{ gt : g\in G \}
$$
**without** always calculating the entire orbit of $t$ under $G$?

### What I Have

I suspect one can use a strong generating set for this; but I can't think of a way to do it.

An interesting reference I found is [arXiv:1211.6261](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.6261.pdf) where, in listing 1, the authors explain how to check whether a tuple is *already* the maximum within the orbit, with worst-case runtime being the size of the orbit. Since I'm looking for a sorting algorithm I would expect a worst-case runtime to be $\Omega( n \log n)$ for a tuple of length $n$; so generating the entire orbit is potentially exponentially worse.

Thanks!
- J

Comment: I don't know much about this field - would an algorithm (assuming the entries are distinct) such as "maximize the first element; calculate the stabilizer of that entry then maximize the second element in that; etc." be reasonably efficient? It's certainly not hard to maximize the first element given a subgroup and this does solve the problem - I don't have a sense of how hard calculating the stabilizer is, though.

Comment: Neat idea! I assume a strong generating set would allow us to iteratively take the stabilizer for the first element, then the second, then the third... etc.. However, "it's certainly not hard to maximize the first element given a subgroup" - could you elaborate? I'm not sure I see how one would do that.

Thanks!!

Comment: I found another reference; it appears this problem is $FP^{NP}$-complete.
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.28.3058

But my general question remains: is there an algorithm that works well in practice? $EXP \gg FP^{NP}$...